# Yii Captcha image was not displayed on Form

Tags: php, yii, captcha

I have a code on view page of Captcha verification . There is no image displayed on here. i also try requirements check of CCaptcha and put code on controller for action redirect. but nothing to be improved .

My view

```
        <?php
        if(CCaptcha::checkRequirements()){
        $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="hint">Please enter the letters as they are shown in the image above.
        <br/>Letters are not case-sensitive.</div>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'verifyCode'); 

                }
         ?>
```

In my controller

```
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
        ),

    );
}
```

this only i get on view . No image displayed

[image: captcha]

Comment: Is there an image-tag in the source code of the page? If so, what's the path to the image?

Comment: maybe you have to check function `accessRules` in your controller. Check if you have set `captcha`.

Comment: yes @davey the path look like this myapp/index.php?r=site/captcha&v=5350b103c062a

Comment: @gultomicro that action access rights are already set by rights extension

Comment: What happens if you call the image path directly in your browser?

Comment: its blank black screen . error shows as cant display the image . i already test this

Comment: @RyanBabu try like this:
`public function accessRules(){'actions'=>array('create','captcha'), 'users'=>array('*')}`

Comment: @gultomicro i already try this . i check that action it has no access problem . that image url contains errors . and i checked the requirements also .

Comment: Is it a blank screen or does it show an error? Does the error come from the browser? Did you try downloading the contents of the response with something like `wget`? If a MIME image header is sent before PHP throws an error you may experience this behavior with some browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @gultomicro

```
public function accessRules(){'actions'=>array('create','captcha'), 'users'=>array('*')}
```

for your answer